# Image Not Uploading to Google Cloud Storage with Multer?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, multer

EDIT: Figured out the issue, solution below.

I'm using multer and multer google storage to try to upload image files to my Google Cloud Bucket, but for some reason the files aren't being saved into the Google Cloud Bucket, and I can't log any errors, not sure what I'm doing wrong here. (Have tried to follow several different tutorials, read documentation, check other SO questions, etc. Still no solution).

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const multerGoogleStorage = require('multer-google-storage');


const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage'); 

const gc = new Storage({
    projectId: '{projectIdRedacted}',
    keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, '../{keyFileNameRedacted.json}')
});

gc.getBuckets().then(x => console.log(x));

// This is showing that I've successfully paired to the Google Cloud bucket. 

const bucket = gc.bucket('{redactedBucketNameHere}');

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    // Reject a file 
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};


var uploadHandler = multer({ 
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(), 
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});

// Testing GCP Bucket Image Upload
// @route   POST image-upload
// @desc    Add image
// @access  Private
router.post('/image-upload', uploadHandler.single('UploadBox'), passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
}), (req, res, next) => {

    // This is showing the req.file is being passed through
    console.log(req.file);

    const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);

    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentType: req.file.mimetype
        },
        resumable: false
    });

    // The err is not getting console logged even though it is not saving to the google cloud bucket properly?
    blobStream.on('error', err => {
        next(err);
        console.log(err);
        return;
    })

    // The publicUrl is not getting console.logged - presumably cause something is breaking before this and it won't save it
    blobStream.on('finish', () => {
        // the public url can be used to directly access the file via HTTP
        const publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`;
        console.log(publicUrl);

        // Make the image public to the web (since we'll be displaying it in the browser)
        blob.makePublic().then(() => {
            res.status(200).send(`Success!\n Image uploaded to ${publicUrl}`);
        })
    })
});
```

The documentation for @google-cloud/storage is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage
The documentation for multer google storage is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-google-storage
The documentation for Google's guide on using their cloud storage is: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage

Any tips and help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I figured out the solution. I had to move up the uploadHandler and the fileFilter ABOVE the const { storage} import. And then inside the route, I had to add "blobStream.end();" after the blobStream.on('finish'). After doing so it resolved it. I've edited the working code below.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const multerGoogleStorage = require('multer-google-storage');


const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    // Reject a file 
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};

var uploadHandler = multer({ 
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(), 
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});


const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage'); 

const gc = new Storage({
    projectId: '{projectIdRedacted}',
    keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, '../{keyFileNameRedacted.json}')
});

gc.getBuckets().then(x => console.log(x));

const bucket = gc.bucket('{bucketNameRedacted}');

// Testing GCP Bucket Image Upload
// @route   POST image-upload
// @desc    Add image
// @access  Private
router.post('/image-upload', uploadHandler.single('UploadBox'), passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
}), (req, res, next) => {

    // This is showing the req.file is being passed through
    console.log(req.file);

    const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);

    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentType: req.file.mimetype
        },
        resumable: false
    });

    // The err is not getting console logged even though it is not saving to the google cloud bucket properly?
    blobStream.on('error', err => {
        next(err);
        console.log(err);
        return;
    })

    // The publicUrl is not getting console.logged - presumably cause something is breaking before this and it won't save it
    blobStream.on('finish', () => {
        // the public url can be used to directly access the file via HTTP
        const publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`;
        console.log(publicUrl);

        // Make the image public to the web (since we'll be displaying it in the browser)
        blob.makePublic().then(() => {
            res.status(200).send(`Success!\n Image uploaded to ${publicUrl}`);
        })
    })

    blobStream.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I had to move up the uploadHandler and the fileFilter ABOVE the const { storage} import. And then inside the route, I had to add "blobStream.end();" after the blobStream.on('finish'). After doing so it resolved it. I've edited the working code below.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const multerGoogleStorage = require('multer-google-storage');


const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    // Reject a file 
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};

var uploadHandler = multer({ 
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(), 
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});


const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage'); 

const gc = new Storage({
    projectId: '{projectIdRedacted}',
    keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, '../{keyFileNameRedacted.json}')
});

gc.getBuckets().then(x => console.log(x));

const bucket = gc.bucket('{bucketNameRedacted}');

// Testing GCP Bucket Image Upload
// @route   POST image-upload
// @desc    Add image
// @access  Private
router.post('/image-upload', uploadHandler.single('UploadBox'), passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
}), (req, res, next) => {

    // This is showing the req.file is being passed through
    console.log(req.file);

    const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);

    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentType: req.file.mimetype
        },
        resumable: false
    });

    // The err is not getting console logged even though it is not saving to the google cloud bucket properly?
    blobStream.on('error', err => {
        next(err);
        console.log(err);


   return;
    })

// The publicUrl is not getting console.logged - presumably cause something is breaking before this and it won't save it
blobStream.on('finish', () => {
    // the public url can be used to directly access the file via HTTP
    const publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`;
    console.log(publicUrl);

    // Make the image public to the web (since we'll be displaying it in the browser)
    blob.makePublic().then(() => {
        res.status(200).send(`Success!\n Image uploaded to ${publicUrl}`);
    })
})

blobStream.end();
});
```

Comment: Using this code, I get a file into my Google Cloud Bucket but it has size 0KB. No other errors. Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Unfortunately no I don't know. Make sure you're using the right file type and the destination is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `multer-google-storage` package, that's by the way.

kindly comment the response error message you get when you hit the route meant for this upload.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got it working. I just had the order confused on some of my imports/declarations. I also had to add blobStream.end(). I've edited my original post with the solution. Thank you for your response though!

Comment: I think this is more of a comment than an answer.